# Folder Access Denied

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, .net-4.5

I was using a winform for reading PDFs from a local folder. everything was just perfect. now that I switched my code to a web service I am getting :

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'path' is
>   denied.

the access to the folder is already set to EVERYONE. and yet I can't read pdf files. Is has nothing to do with IIS?

Comment: To be answerable such question need [MCVE]. Note that 95% of questions with this exception endup being "I want to use directory name as file path" (or other way around) - save your time and check that first (feel free to delete question if it is the case).

Comment: Did you replace the path in the exception so we don't see your directory structure? If you didn't, then the path throwing the exception is literally `path`: `Access to the path 'path' is denied`, which, I assume, is not a valid path (unless the program's working directory contains a folder named `path`).

Comment: The path is absolutely valid. I specified an administrator account for the web service to run under it. it's worked well. now that I am trying read PDFs from a folder in network, I get the same error

Comment: It's fixed. it may be helpful for others. I run the service under an **network administrator account**.